# Smooth detour from one function to another

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, interpolation

Suppose I am given two smooth functions $f$ and $g$ on the real line and real numbers $a<b$ such that $f(a)<g(b)$ and $f'(a),g'(b)\ge0$

I want to get a smooth $H:\mathbb R\rightarrow\mathbb R$ such that

1. $H\equiv f$ on $(-\infty,a]$

   $H\equiv g$ on $[b,\infty)$

   $H'>0$ on $(a,b)$

This is how I went about it:

Set $$H=f(1-h)+gh$$where $h:\mathbb R\rightarrow\mathbb R$ is smooth such that $h\equiv0$ on $(-\infty,a]$ and $h\equiv1$ on $[b,\infty)$

Here $h$ in turn is found using the function $F(x)=j(x-a)j(b-x)$ where $j$ is the well-known function:$$j(x)=\begin{cases}e^{-\frac1{x^2}}&x>0\\0&x\le0\end{cases}$$

Notice that $F$ vanishes outside $[a,b]$. We use $F$ in the following way to construct $h$
$$h(x)=\frac{\int_{-\infty}^xF(x)}{\int_{-\infty}^\infty F(x)}$$

So one checks that $H$ satisfies the requirements of the first paragraph except for (3).

My question is how to tweak $H$ so that (3) too is satisfied?

In fact proof of mere existence of such $H$ that (1),(2) and (3) are satisfied, holds good for me. Is there a theorem I can employ?

Comment: Firstly, you need that $f(a) \leq g(b)$ otherwise $3$ cannot be satisfied at all, so that is another implicit assumption.

Comment: Thanks! I do require that, edited my question.

Comment: I'm not sure if it's a worthwhile idea but what about looking at some sort of convolution definition for $H$ in the interval $(a,b)$? The convolution of two smooth functions is again smooth (provided the integral makes sense of course).

Comment: Do you mean the $f\star g(t)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(t-\tau)g(\tau)d\tau$? That is thus far the only definition I know of.

Comment: If $H$ is smooth and $H' > 0$ on $(a,b)$, then it would be necessary to have $H'(a) = f'(a) \geq 0$ and $H'(b) = g'(b) \geq 0$. In other words, if either $f'(a)$ or $g'(b)$ is negative, such interpolation can't be done. Can you make such assumptions on the derivatives at $a,b$?

Comment: Noticed. Already edited.

Comment: @AneeshKarthikC If you want to use your $f(1-h)+gh$ idea, $h(x) = \left\{\begin{array}{cc} 0 & x \le a \\ \exp\left(\frac{1}{(a-b)^2}\right)\exp\left(-\frac{1}{(a-b)^2-(x-b)^2}\right) & a < x < b \\ 1 & b \le x\end{array}\right.$ will work if $f'$ is nondecreasing on $(a,b)$, $g' \ge f'$ on $(a,b)$ and $f > g$ on $(a,b)$. These conditions are sufficient to have that $H = f(1-h)+gh$ be increasing on $(a,b)$.